# Any way to synchronize table column widths with HTML + CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a number of tables with the same columns and it would look a lot nicer if they shared the same column widths.  Is such a thing possible?  Putting them in the same table with some rows with no borders between them isn't an option.

**Edit:** Yeah I'm aware I can fix the widths myself but I was hoping for something that would tie in to the browser's column width algorithm but simply tied two or more tables together for the purpose of doing that layout.

I didn't think such a thing was possible but I thought I'd check just in case.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's only possible if you can fix-width the columns.  If you can set a fixed width then some css like this should work:

```
td {
    width: 25%;
}
```

You can customize each columns width like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="col1">...</td>
    <td class="col2">...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
...
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="col1">...</td>
    <td class="col2">...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and then specify the widths like this:

```
.col1 {
   width: 25%;
}
.col2 {
   width: 75%;
}
```

Comment: Err, no it isn't the only way.  Please see my answer!

Answer (score 50):

If you're not too picky about which column widths the browser comes up with, as long as they're the same across different tables, you can use the CSS [`table-layout`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#propdef-table-layout) property (supported by all major browsers) in combination with a table width:

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This causes all columns (without a specified width) to have the same width, regardless of the table content.

Comment: …at the expense of making columns so narrow that not even a word can be rendered in a cell without overflowing when the width of the viewport is narrow or there are enough columns that you’d want horizontal scrolling, right?

Comment: That depends on the contents of your table, doesn't it? If that's what you get, then this is clearly not the best solution. But you can also combine this solution with some of the others. I.e. use `table-layout: fixed` as well as set fixed widths on some columns/cells.

Answer (score 17):

Here's a small JavaScript I made to resize cells to make them equal width in all tables on a page.

```
function resizeTables()
{
    var tableArr = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
    var cellWidths = new Array();

    // get widest
    for(i = 0; i < tableArr.length; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < tableArr[i].rows[0].cells.length; j++)
        {
           var cell = tableArr[i].rows[0].cells[j];

           if(!cellWidths[j] || cellWidths[j] < cell.clientWidth)
                cellWidths[j] = cell.clientWidth;
        }
    }

    // set all columns to the widest width found
    for(i = 0; i < tableArr.length; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < tableArr[i].rows[0].cells.length; j++)
        {
            tableArr[i].rows[0].cells[j].style.width = cellWidths[j]+'px';
        }
    }
}

window.onload = resizeTables;
```

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Ken's answer, you can also specify the exact widths in pixels:

```
td { width: 250px }
```

or ems (width of the letter m):

```
td { width: 32em }
```

or ex or pt or whatever (well...actually %, pt, px, em, ex might be it).  If you need your columns to be different widths, then the easy way is to give the table cells classes:

```
<table><tr>
    <td class="col1">...</td><td class="col2">...</td>...
</tr></table>
```

and assign column widths to the classes:

```
td.col1 { width: 48em }
td.col2 { width: 200px }
...
```

It should be sufficient to assign column widths to the first row in each table.  *[edit: looks like I've been scooped on that while I was writing]*

You could probably also go crazy with the CSS 2 sibling selector, and write something like

```
tr > td:first-child { width:48em } /* first column */
tr > td:first-child + td { width: 200px } /* second column */
tr > td:first-child + td + td { width: 5% } /* third column  */
...
```

but if you have more than a few columns, that could get ugly.  And if you're using some sort of template system or script to generate these tables, I'm sure it'll be easier/clearer to just put the class="col#" attribute on each cell in your template once.

Comment: That sibling selector is unsupported on a few browsers I think.  Probably unsupported on IE6, maybe even IE7.

Comment: Yep, it works on browsers that follow the W3C standard for CSS.  IE6 and 7 generally don't follow the standards, but IE8 might. (Firefox and most minor browsers do, of course.)

Comment: The adjacent sibling selector and :first-child pseudo-class do work in IE7; not in IE6. But I think this a prime example of something you can drop for IE6, unless you specifically need to support IE6 (e.g. on an intranet). Nothing would break without it. It would just not look as nice.

Answer (score 3):

I'm almost shocked that no one has suggested [column groups](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/tables/colgroup.html)!  With it you can give a column a specific class, width, and other helpful properties.  And since it's HTML 4.01 it's supported by all browsers that support the doctype.

Comment: I believe colgroups aren't supported by IE, no?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but how to colgroups actually help for this problem?

Comment: As far as I know, colgroups are supported by IE.  As a part of the standard they ought to be ... but the IE team thinks that they're special.

Comment: Cletus: if there are a uniform number of columns, you can apply to all relevant tables the colgroup.  Even by javascript if you wish.

Comment: But this is just another variation on fixing the widths of all the tables/columns, yes?

Comment: There is nothing in the specification that I can see which would linkup two separate tables this way.

Answer (score 3):

Luis Siquot answer is the one I used. However instead of using clientWidth, you should use jquery width() function to normalize widths between browsers, and to not calculate padding. Using clientWidth would result in the table cells expanding on ajaxpostbacks because of the padding (if padding used in the TD's).
So, correct code using Luis Siquot's answer would be to replace

```
var cell = $(this)[0].rows[0].cells[j];
       if(!cellWidths[j] || cellWidths[j] < cell.clientWidth) cellWidths[j] = cell.clientWidth;
```

with

```
var cell = $($(this)[0].rows[0].cells[j]);
            if (!cellWidths[j] || cellWidths[j] < cell.width()) cellWidths[j] = cell.width();
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is kind of a 'dirty' way, but it works the best.
It does exactly what's required:

Just merge your two tables into one table.
In my case the only thing between the two tables was an `h3`

So my table

```
<table>
<tr></tr>
<table>

<h3>Title<h3>

<table>
<tr></tr>
<table>
```

became this:

```
<table>
<tr></tr>

<tr><td colspan="6">
<h3>Title<h3>
</td></tr>

<tr></tr>
<table>
```

this way your table will 'sync' it's size up.
of course this only works when there isn't too much complex stuff in between the two tables, but I'm guessing in most cases it isn't. if it was, the sync wouldn't be needed in the first place.

Comment: This is the only solution I've been about to come up with in a few cases. It's extremely tedious though and can make for some unpleasant amount of colspans as well as hitting various quirks (borders hell too). I recommend that you also add to use tbody, thead, caption, etc to improve breaking up the table into alternate types of table with the appropriate stylings.

Comment: Also, it prohibits you from using thead or tfoot easily. Additionally it means that you can't separate out content sizing. If table type a has a really long first column, b a short first column, it will be really long for table b. This could make another colspan nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

each pair of tables resize its columns to the same width
similar to **Ole J. Helgesen** but with jquery and a parameter in order to select which tables equalize.
(I cant vote but it's essentially your solution)

```
<table data-ss="1" border="1">
  <tr><td>asdf<td>129292<td>text
</table>
<table data-ss="1" border=1>
  <tr><td>a<td>1<td>each column here has the same size than the table above
</table>
<table data-ss="2" border=1>
  <tr><td>asdf<td>129292<td>text
</table>
<table data-ss="2" border=1>
  <tr><td>each column here has the same size than the table above<td>a<td>1
</table>
```

and use this sctipt

```
$(function(){
  resizeTables('1');
  resizeTables('2');
});

//please set table html attribute `data-ss="something"` to properly call this js
// ss is short for SharedSize
function resizeTables(sharedSize){
  var tableArr = $('table[data-ss='+sharedSize+']');
  var cellWidths = new Array();
  $(tableArr).each(function() {
    for(j = 0; j < $(this)[0].rows[0].cells.length; j++){
       var cell = $(this)[0].rows[0].cells[j];
       if(!cellWidths[j] || cellWidths[j] < cell.clientWidth) cellWidths[j] = cell.clientWidth;
    }
  });
  $(tableArr).each(function() {
    for(j = 0; j < $(this)[0].rows[0].cells.length; j++){
        $(this)[0].rows[0].cells[j].style.width = cellWidths[j]+'px';
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sync the column widths by combining the tables (as suggested by @Stefanvds), but using a `tbody` + `th` for each:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table thead,
table tbody {
  border-bottom: solid;
}

table tbody th {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr> <th> ID <th> Measurement <th> Average <th> Maximum
  <tbody>
    <tr> <td> <th scope=rowgroup> Cats <td> <td>
    <tr> <td> 93 <th scope=row> Legs <td> 3.5 <td> 4
    <tr> <td> 10 <th scope=row> Tails <td> 1 <td> 1
  <tbody>
    <tr> <td> <th scope=rowgroup> English speakers <td> <td>
    <tr> <td> 32 <th scope=row> Legs <td> 2.67 <td> 4
    <tr> <td> 35 <th scope=row> Tails <td> 0.33 <td> 1
</table>
```

Source: [Example in the HTML spec itself](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-th-element)